# Unable to update MacPorts: "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: macports

I'm trying to run `sudo port selfupdate` to but part of the build process seems to be generating errors. I've run it with `-d`, and here's the output:

```
DEBUG: MacPorts sources location: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 69 bytes  42.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3236352  speedup is 30822.40
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 76 bytes  74.67 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 4.57
DEBUG: successful verification with key /opt/local/share/macports/macports-pubkey.pem
DEBUG: /usr/bin/tar -C /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/tmp -xf /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar
MacPorts base version 2.0.3 installed,
DEBUG: Rebuilding and reinstalling MacPorts if needed
MacPorts base version 2.0.4 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree
DEBUG: Synchronizing ports tree(s)
Synchronizing local ports tree from rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after  rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 70 bytes  70.67 bytes/sec
total size is 50160128  speedup is 473208.75
DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after  rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar.rmd160 /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 77 bytes  75.33 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 4.53
DEBUG: successful verification with key /opt/local/share/macports/macports-pubkey.pem
DEBUG: /usr/bin/tar -C /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/tmp -xf /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/PortIndex_darwin_11_i386/PortIndex /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 70 bytes  42.40 bytes/sec
total size is 7752083  speedup is 73132.86
DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/PortIndex_darwin_11_i386/PortIndex.rmd160 /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 77 bytes  75.33 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 4.53
DEBUG: successful verification with key /opt/local/share/macports/macports-pubkey.pem
--->  MacPorts base is outdated, installing new version 2.0.4
DEBUG: Permissions OK
Installing new MacPorts release in /opt/local as root:admin; permissions 0755; Tcl-Package in /Library/Tcl

checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0
checking MacPorts version... 2.0.4
checking for sw_vers... /usr/bin/sw_vers
checking for defaults... /usr/bin/defaults
checking for xcode-select... /usr/bin/xcode-select
checking Mac OS X version... 10.7.3
checking Xcode location... /Developer
checking Xcode version... 4.2
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out

[truncated due to 30000 character limit!]

checking whether rl_completion_matches is declared... yes
checking whether username_completion_function is declared... yes
checking whether filename_completion_function is declared... yes
checking whether completion_matches is declared... yes
checking for Tcl configuration... found /usr/lib/tclConfig.sh
checking for existence of /usr/lib/tclConfig.sh... loading
checking for Tcl public headers... /usr/include
checking for tclsh... /usr/bin/tclsh
checking for Tcl package directory... /Library/Tcl
checking whether tclsh was compiled with threads... yes
checking for curl-config... /usr/bin/curl-config
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking sqlite3ext.h usability... yes
checking sqlite3ext.h presence... yes
checking for sqlite3ext.h... yes
checking for Tcl sqlite3 location... 
checking for Tcl Thread package... yes
checking how to build libraries... shared
checking that any existing MacPorts install can be upgraded... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/programs/daemondo/Makefile
config.status: creating Doxyfile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating Mk/macports.autoconf.mk
config.status: creating doc/base.mtree
config.status: creating doc/prefix.mtree
config.status: creating doc/macosx.mtree
config.status: creating doc/macports.conf
config.status: creating doc/pubkeys.conf
config.status: creating portmgr/freebsd/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating src/macports1.0/macports_autoconf.tcl
config.status: creating src/port1.0/port_autoconf.tcl
config.status: creating src/registry2.0/registry_autoconf.tcl
config.status: creating src/programs/Makefile
config.status: creating src/macports1.0/macports_fastload.tcl
config.status: creating setupenv.bash
config.status: creating src/pkg_mkindex.sh
config.status: creating src/config.h
===> making all in doc
gzip -c port.1 > port.1.gz
gzip -c macports.conf.5 > macports.conf.5.gz
gzip -c portfile.7 > portfile.7.gz
gzip -c portstyle.7 > portstyle.7.gz
gzip -c porthier.7 > porthier.7.gz
gzip -c portgroup.7 > portgroup.7.gz
===> making all in src
===> making all in src/cregistry
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common registry.c -o registry.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common entry.c -o entry.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common sql.c -o sql.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common vercomp.c -o vercomp.o
ar cr cregistry.a registry.o entry.o sql.o vercomp.o
ranlib cregistry.a
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common sqlext.c -o sqlext.o
/usr/bin/cc -dynamiclib -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic   -Wl,-single_module sqlext.o vercomp.o -o macports.sqlext
===> making all in src/macports1.0
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common macports.c -o macports.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common get_systemconfiguration_proxies.c -o get_systemconfiguration_proxies.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common sysctl.c -o sysctl.o
/usr/bin/cc -dynamiclib -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic   -Wl,-single_module macports.o get_systemconfiguration_proxies.o sysctl.o -o MacPorts.dylib -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5 -ltclstub8.5   -framework CoreFoundation -framework SystemConfiguration
===> making all in src/port1.0
===> making all in src/package1.0
===> making all in src/pextlib1.0
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common Pextlib.c -o Pextlib.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common strsed.c -o strsed.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common fgetln.c -o fgetln.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common md5cmd.c -o md5cmd.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common setmode.c -o setmode.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common xinstall.c -o xinstall.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common fs-traverse.c -o fs-traverse.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common strcasecmp.c -o strcasecmp.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common vercomp.c -o vercomp.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common filemap.c -o filemap.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common base32cmd.c -o base32cmd.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common sha1cmd.c -o sha1cmd.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common curl.c -o curl.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common rmd160cmd.c -o rmd160cmd.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common sha256cmd.c -o sha256cmd.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common readline.c -o readline.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common uid.c -o uid.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common tracelib.c -o tracelib.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common tty.c -o tty.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common readdir.c -o readdir.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common pipe.c -o pipe.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common flock.c -o flock.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common system.c -o system.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common mktemp.c -o mktemp.o
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic     -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common realpath.c -o realpath.o
/usr/bin/cc -dynamiclib -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic      -Wl,-single_module Pextlib.o strsed.o fgetln.o md5cmd.o setmode.o xinstall.o fs-traverse.o strcasecmp.o vercomp.o filemap.o base32cmd.o sha1cmd.o curl.o rmd160cmd.o sha256cmd.o readline.o uid.o tracelib.o tty.o readdir.o pipe.o flock.o system.o mktemp.o realpath.o -o Pextlib.dylib -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5 -ltclstub8.5   -lcurl  -lreadline
===> making all in src/registry2.0
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -I/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common registry.c -o registry.o
In file included from ../cregistry/registry.h:35,
                 from registry.c:39:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include/sqlite3.h:252: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include/sqlite3.h:253: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -I/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common util.c -o util.o
In file included from util.h:36,
                 from util.c:37:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include/sqlite3.h:252: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include/sqlite3.h:253: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -I/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common entry.c -o entry.o
In file included from entry.c:36:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include/sqlite3.h:252: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include/sqlite3.h:253: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’
/usr/bin/cc -c -DUSE_TCL_STUBS -DTCL_NO_DEPRECATED -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -I/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.. -I.  -I"/usr/include" -fno-common entryobj.c -o entryobj.o
In file included from entryobj.c:36:
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include/sqlite3.h:252: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include/sqlite3.h:253: warning: ISO C90 does not support ‘long long’
/usr/bin/cc -dynamiclib -g -O2 -W -Wall -pedantic  -I/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/include    -Wl,-single_module registry.o util.o entry.o entryobj.o ../cregistry/cregistry.a -o registry.dylib -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5 -ltclstub8.5   -L/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/lib -lsqlite3  
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.6/lib/libsqlite3.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      _set_sqlite_result in util.o
      _reg_sqlite_error in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_detach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_close in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_attach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_open in cregistry.a(registry.o)
  "_sqlite3_mprintf", referenced from:
      _set_object in util.o
      _set_entry in util.o
      _get_object in util.o
      _reg_sqlite_error in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_detach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_attach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_open in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_free", referenced from:
      _set_object in util.o
      _set_entry in util.o
      _get_object in util.o
      _reg_throw in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_sqlite_error in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_detach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_attach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_prepare", referenced from:
      _all_objects in util.o
      _reg_vacuum in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_detach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_attach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_entry_create in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_depends in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_all_entries in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
      _all_objects in util.o
      _reg_all_entries in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_owner in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_open in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_owner_id in cregistry.a(entry.o)
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      _all_objects in util.o
      _reg_vacuum in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_detach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_attach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_entry_create in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_depends in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_all_entries in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      _all_objects in util.o
      _reg_vacuum in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_detach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_attach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_entry_create in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_depends in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_all_entries in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      _reg_vacuum in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_open in cregistry.a(registry.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      _reg_vacuum in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_close in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_open in cregistry.a(registry.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      _reg_vacuum in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_detach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_attach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_entry_deactivate in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_activate in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_unmap in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_map in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_vmprintf", referenced from:
      _reg_throw in cregistry.a(registry.o)
  "_sqlite3_errcode", referenced from:
      _reg_sqlite_error in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_detach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_attach in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_open in cregistry.a(registry.o)
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      _reg_rollback in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_commit in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_start_write in cregistry.a(registry.o)
      _reg_start_read in cregistry.a(registry.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      _reg_entry_create in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_depends in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_owner in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_open in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_owner_id in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_deactivate in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_activate in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_last_insert_rowid", referenced from:
      _reg_entry_create in cregistry.a(entry.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
      _reg_entry_depends in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_delete in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_deactivate in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_activate in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_unmap in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_map in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_files in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_changes", referenced from:
      _reg_entry_delete in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_deactivate in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_activate in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_unmap in cregistry.a(entry.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      _reg_entry_files in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_imagefiles in cregistry.a(entry.o)
      _reg_entry_propget in cregistry.a(entry.o)
  "_sqlite3_value_text", referenced from:
      _sql_regexp in cregistry.a(sql.o)
  "_sqlite3_result_int", referenced from:
      _sql_regexp in cregistry.a(sql.o)
  "_sqlite3_result_error", referenced from:
      _sql_regexp in cregistry.a(sql.o)
  "_sqlite3_create_function", referenced from:
      _init_db in cregistry.a(sql.o)
  "_sqlite3_create_collation", referenced from:
      _init_db in cregistry.a(sql.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [registry.dylib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
shell command "cd /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base && CC=/usr/bin/cc ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-tclpackage=/Library/Tcl --with-install-user=root --with-install-group=admin --with-directory-mode=0755 --enable-readline && make && make install SELFUPDATING=1" returned error 2
DEBUG: Error installing new MacPorts base: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"macports::selfupdate [array get global_options] base_updated"
Error: /opt/local/bin/port: port selfupdate failed: Error installing new MacPorts base: shell command failed (see log for details)
```

It looks like it's something to do with sqlite3, but I'm not really sure what to search for to find a solution. I've tried some cursory searches on the output around where it runs aground, but with no luck.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's caused by a non-MacPorts Mono installation, whose sqlite3 is being linked against by MacPorts. To work around the problem I temporarily moved `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework` to somewhere else and re-ran `port selfupdate`.

Details: http://trac.macports.org/ticket/25318